# Port an iPhone app to Mac OS X

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I have an app running on the iPhone that I would like to convert into a runnable application on Mac OS X. It uses a single UIViewController, which I have heard needs to be changed into an NSViewController.

Basically what I am wondering is what needs to be changed about an iPhone application to make it work like a Mac application instead, for instance, is there a mac UIKit equivalent? Or how do I use the Mac interface objects that show up in interface builder, things like this. Is there anything that needs to be fundamentally different about the structure of the code for it to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ApplicationKit](http://objc.toodarkpark.net/AppKit/ApplicationKitTOC.html) is where you should look.

Comment: so basically that is all I need to change and it will run(besides obviously the other references to UIKit)?